# Formatting String into MYSQL time

Tags: php, mysql, string, time

Ok, So i have a script that reads in a csv file and in there is a time that is formatted in the traditional HH:MM am/pm. I need to convert that into the mysql standard time format (HH:MM:SS).

This is what i have so far and it works

```
$schedule[$row]["TIME"] = date("H:i:s", strtotime($data[4]))
```

the problem is, if the input is formatted incorrectly there is no way i can tell. Is there some sort of "or die()" feature i can use or do i have to somehow check with a regex or something?

For example:

12:00 pm should be 12:00:00
but...if theres some issue with the format
12:d00 p.m comes out as 17:00:00

Thanks,
Ian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`strtotime`](http://php.net/strtotime) returns false if the parsing fails. So you can do:

```
$t = strtotime($data[4]);
if ($t === false)
    //handle error
$schedule[$row]["TIME"] = date("H:i:s", $t);
```

Comment: Please be aware that in older 5.x versions of PHP, a failed `strtotime` can return `-1` instead of false.